# How to choose the right amount of training dataset for forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, training-data

I have a dataset which has around 4 years of history data with weekly seasonality. I have started with taking the last 1 year as training dataset and forecasted about 30 data points. But reducing the training dataset to 6 months in some cases is giving me better forecasting values.

Reading online, k fold cross validation seems to be one technique to identify the correct volume of training dataset.

Am i correct on this?

In general, can any one please recommend efficient ways to select the right amount of training dataset?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to identify suitable training set sizes a priori, particularly knowing nothing (as we do) about the structure of the data.

ASSUMING that you are endeavoring to derive a LINEAR CLASSIFIER for a set of observations ("training samples") characterized as N COMPONENTS of a MESSAGE VECTOR in an N-DIMENSIONAL KOTELNIKOFF HYPERSPACE, a "suitable size" for a training set is one that enables subsequent samples to be correctly classified but does not start causing classification errors.

Put another way, if data newly added to a monotonic database cannot be properly classified, then the problem turns out to be linearly inseparable.  Trick your clients by stopping well before that point, so that the system can appear to function impressively for some time BEFORE you reach the point where linear inseparability can no longer be danced around.

Which dance?  Why, the Voronoi dance, of course (a BITTERLY POOR digital communication theory joke)

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently learning and applying Machine Learning and I have found, from my research, that if you have split your data into a training set and a testing set, and if your training set is smaller than your testing set your model will have bad predictive performance. On the other hand if you put too few data points in your test set and beef up your training set then you would have a bad approximation to your generalization error. There is no perfect way to split your training set and testing set, but a general rule of thumb is too have a good amount of training error to approximate generalization error well and you want to rest of your data in your test set. This is can be represented by splits like 60% training and 40% testing or 70% training and 30% testing or 90% training data and 10% testing data. This is adequate if you have a very large dataset.

Now, if you have a small amount of data and you don't have the ability to avoid the two situations I mentioned earlier then k-fold cross validation could be the answer to your problem, but first let me explain another method of splitting your data. Earlier I showed you a way to split your data into a training set and a testing set. But I want to introduce to you something called the **validation set**.

The two most important tasks in Regression (and all other topics in Machine Learning for that matter) is choosing a **specific model complexity**, so if you are working with Polynomial Regression you would be concerned about what **degree** your working with, and finally, for the model that you select you need to **assess it's performance**. Now, for the first task, choosing a specific model, let **λ** represent a tuning parameter that controls the complexity of our model. For example λ would specify the degree of my polynomial if I were to work with Polynomial regression. Now let us picture a hypothetical situation where I split my data set into a training set and testing set, and let us perform the two tasks I mentioned earlier.

```
------------------------------------------
|    Training set            | Test set   |
------------------------------------------
```

1. **Model Selection:**

   - For each model complexity you consider: λ
   - i. Estimate your weights on training set
   - ii. Assess the performance with your testing set
   - iii. Choose the model complexity λ that has the lowest test error
2. **Assessing Performance:** When you find the best model complexity or model in general (let this be denoted as **λ***), we simply assess the performance by computing it's test error.

Here is the problem with **only have a training set and a testing set**. This approach of only working with a training set and testing set is overly optimistic. When we were thinking about choosing a specific model complexity we were using our **test set/data** to compare between different λ values and we chose the λ that minimized the test error. But this implies that we are using test error as a way to approximate how well we will do with new data. The issue is our test data doesn't represent everything we might see out there in the world (i.e all possible data that can be encountered by our model). Our model was specifically chosen to do well on test data. A better solution is have two "test sets": a **training set, a validation set , and a test set**.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|    Training set         | Validation set  | Test set   |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now the question is how do we select a model and assess it's performance with a second test set? Here is how we can do it.

- 1. Fit our model on our **training set**/data for every model complexity we are considering (λ).
- 2. We will select the best model/model complexity/λ based on which model minimizes the error on the **validation set**.
- 3. Finally, we assess the performance of the best model/model complexity/λ on the **test set**. Now the test set can be considered an approximation of our generalization error since it was never used.

Now you may be wondering, how do I split this group of data now that I have two test sets? Here are the most typical splits:

- 80% training set, 10% validation set , 10% testing set
- 50% training set, 25% validation set , 25% testing set

These splits are recommended if you have a sufficient amount of data. Now if you don't have enough data to divide up your data into these 3 sets. One way to use all of our data to assess the performance of your model is using K-Fold cross validation and I would recommend using this method if you have a small data set. As of the writing of this post I have not worked with a dataset as large as what you have described, but It wouldn't hurt to give K-Fold Validation a try and compare it with other methods to see what works best with your model.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response Guled! I i will try the recommendations you have provided.